# android: app start more slowly after size grown

Tags: android, android-library

My app is about 10M in size. It start quickly.

Recently, for some reason, my app include a library project which has little java code and a very large dynamic library about 60M. And then, my app start with a full screen white and go into my first Activity after about five second.

However I don't load the large lib when start, instead I load it when I use the feature.

Why so slowly? Isn't Android load dynamic library into RAM when I call `System.loadLibrary()` ?

How should I do to shorten the time of start-up?

Comment: How do you reference the library in your project? Are you sure it doensn't get loaded at start?

Comment: @Axel App do load the dynamic lib xxxx.so when I use the feather.I can see the loading log of dalvikvm when I click the button.

Comment: Could it be it's just loaded a second time (for whatever reason) when you click the button?

Comment: @Axel I checked my code and log while starting. It do not load the large dynamic library while starting.